# Cucumber BeforeStep

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Is there a BeforeStep equivalent to AfterStep in Cucumber?

If not - has anyone found a solution / workaround?

Comment: It would help to know what you want to do with a BeforeStep.  Are you trying to do something before every single step?  Or are you trying to set data up for certain tests?

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation on Hooks on the [Cucumber Wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) on GitHub, the answer is no. There is `Before` but no `BeforeStep`. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, `Before` might do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

So far as `Before` is executed before each scenario and `AfterStep` - after each step in scenario, to achieve *BeforeStep* you can simply place you code in both hooks: Before and AfterStep.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the beginning of every step, whatever I set gets reset and doesn't work with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is quite outdated question but:

Before might be used explicitly e.g before scenario but sometimes it is pointles due to fact that it pollute scenarios description.

I use in support/hooks.rb e.g

> Before do |scenario|
>   //something which should be executed before each scenario
>   end

It might be usefull in case when some action action must be repeted before EVERY scenario in test set.

Answer (score 0):

I am running cucumber within TestNG. I'd like to print the step definition names out as the feature file is processed. This doesn't appear to happen when running under TestNG. If I had a BeforesStep annotation on a method such as beforeStep(StepDefinition sd)
(or something like that), I'd log the step definition name. That would ve very useful.

Is there a different way to do this with Java Cucumber ?