# Automatically switching PostgreSQL schemas before every step in Cucumber -- "BeforeStep"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cucumber

I'm trying to test a multi-tenant PostgreSQL app with Cucumber. It seems that the database connection is reset in every step, thus the need to set the `schema_search_path` in every step. I know about hooks, and looked for `BeforeStep`, but [there's none](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1408239/61018). That post mentioned using a combination of `Before` and `AfterStep` but that doesn't work either, because the `schema_search_path` is reset before every step.

**How do I automatically and DRYly switch database before everystep, so that my Cuke world is consistenant with the Application session?**

Want to see details? Here's my setup now (Note: I'm using the [Apartment gem](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment) to do the switching):

```
Before do
  # ...
  Apartment::Database.switch @current_site.subdomain if @current_site
  # ...
end

AfterStep do
  puts "start of AfterStep. current_database: #{Apartment::Database.current_database}"
  # ...
  Apartment::Database.switch @current_site.subdomain if @current_site
  # ...
  puts "end of AfterStep. current_database: #{Apartment::Database.current_database}"
end
```

Then I have some steps:

```
Given /^a site "([^"]*)" exists$/ do |site_name|
  @current_site = Site.make! :name => site_name, :subdomain => site_name.downcase.underscore
  Apartment::Database.switch @current_site.subdomain
end

When /^I upload an image to the image field$/ do
  image_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/5x5.jpg"
  puts "About to attach_file. that's controlled by selenium so the ApplicationController should switch for us."
  attach_file "File", image_path
  puts "current site: #{@current_site.subdomain}"
  puts "In the schema #{Apartment::Database.current_database}"
  sleep 2
  puts "Here are all images in #{Apartment::Database.current_database}: #{Image.all.inspect}"
end
```

And here's how the cucumber output looks like for that step:

```
Given the site "Fancake" exists
# Other steps...
When I upload an image to the image field
  About to attach_file. that's controlled by selenium so the ApplicationController should switch for us.
  current site: fancake
  In the schema "$user",public
  Here are all images in "$user",public: []
  start of AfterStep. current_database: "$user",public
  end of AfterStep. current_database: fancake
```

Answer (score 1):

How does your application switch schemas? Your Cucumber steps should do it the same way (probably through the app UI).

And why bother with schemas? A multi-tenant application should normally store all data in one schema: it's easier to break data up if it's stored together than to glue data together if it's stored apart.

Comment: The app switches schemas in a before_filter run in every request. Problem with that is that using a factory won't work - I'll need to create everything through the UI.

Comment: Why bother with schemas? Because I need to be able to replicate a site easily. With schemas I can copy the data of one schema to another schema. If the data is all mixed up, then I will have to copy data programmatically, inspecting all relationships. I've tried this and it's very difficult and error prone.

Comment: Then your data probably isn't stored optimally. It shouldn't be tedious or error-prone to do this if you're modeling the data correctly, I think.

Comment: I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary with the way my relationships are. But how would you go about Copying what a site has with all its pages, its images, etc, and update the `foreign_ids` appropriately?

Comment: Not to mention that some of these relationships are polymorphic. And some are `has_many_throughs`. And, when relationships change, my code that "copies" will have to change too. I've thought about this for over a week already.

Comment: Updating foreign keys will be easy. You're using Postgres, so you have foreign key constraints that work, right? (If not, install Foreigner and put some in.) Turn on `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. Done. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: That sounds like a nice thing -- didn't know about that. Though I still don't know how to use it to *duplicate* a site, and all its contents. I'll be making some pseudo code and will paste it here to better express my thoughts on this.

Comment: [Here's the pseudo code](https://gist.github.com/1399836). It's still not clear to me for more than super simple relationships. In that example I posted, a site has_many pages, and has_many images. However, a page can also have those same images. How then do I make sure that I don't copy the same image over? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I also want to eventually backup each site, individually, to give each tenant a copy of their data. Right now that isn't trivial. And, what's even less trivial is the fact that I don't know how to import this later on and keep the relationships intact.

Comment: It seems to me that you could copy a site in one query with the `INSERT...SELECT` construct. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: For backup, again, you should be able to get all the data in one big-ass query with appropriate joins. Importation is a rather different concern, I think.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems much simpler to just learn how to test it, than to worry about exporting and importing it properly.

Comment: It may seem that way, but I *think* you'll find that having all the data together has other advantages. If it were just a question of testing, I'd probably agree with you, but that's not the case IMHO.

Comment: For what it's worth, I started schemas. Then moved to put all data together because schema support in Rails 3 broke a bit. But with a better understanding and the Apartment gem, I'm fairly confident that it will serve me better to have schemas separate for what I want to do. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It's unlikely, but I'll leave you to experiment on your own... :D

Comment: I have more than experimented I think. It was all on the public schema for about 8 months. I don't need to share data anyways -- I understand that's a major concern of people when using multiple schemas. What's your concern when data is split up into schemas? Why do you seem very much against it?

Comment: Basically, data shouldn't be split up more than necessary. If you have each customer's data separate, it is harder than it should be to look at aggregate statistics and usage patterns. OTOH, if all the data is together, it's easy to split it up ad hoc. In other words: ad hoc splitting of one schema is easier than ad hoc joining of many schemas. Therefore, keep everything together in one schema.

Comment: You have good points. I am at a crossroad, however. Either learn how to do the SQL required to export/import/copy tenants, or to live with the consequences (and benefits too) of splitting them up to schemas. Perhaps when I'm done with this and I find it nearly impossible to do another task, I'll look back at this and do a facepalm. :)

Comment: And btw, there are some tables that will remain common to all. I could save into those tables the things that will compute stats and stuff. At the moment though that's far away from the roadmap.

Comment: Learn the SQL. At that point, you will be in a better position to decide what the proper solution is.

Comment: There's one thing that bothers me about this: having to update the export/import process every time there is a change in the data structure. It's this alone that makes me biased towards splitting it up into different schemas.

Comment: Why do you think the presence or absence of schemas would have any effect on this?